# Replace a string by another string in an "array"

Tags: python, regex

My file so far looks like this:

```
[
{
    "asks" : [
        [
            0.00276477,
            NumberInt(9)
        ],
        [
            0.00276478,
            NumberInt(582)]]

}
]
```

I would like to replace the "NumberInt(9)" by the digit 9.

What I tried so far looks like this:

```
json_data=open("test.json").read()
number = re.findall("NumberInt\(([0-9]+)\)", json_data)
Nint = re.findall("(Nu.*)", json_data)
json_data.replace('Nint', 'number')
```

But it does not replace it in my original file... Does someone has an idea?

Comment: While this is *possible*, you might consider fixing whatever's serving (or generating) you that broken JSON instead, that would surely be more elegant than a monkeypatch like this

Comment: Thanks for this comment, but for now I do not have other solution than working on this file... sorry

Comment: You may check out the string after replace, if it was replaced, the answer may be you just forget to write it back to the org file.

Comment: See the [**Search and Replace**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) section of the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) in the documentation. With respect to your current code: Note that the string `replace()` function _returns_ the modified string—it doesn't change it in-place because strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: replace returns a new string, strings are not mutable maybe are you missing `json_data = json_data.replace('Nint', 'number')`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it, based on the documentation of [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
with open("test.json") as file: 
    json_data = file.read()
new_json = re.sub("NumberInt\(([0-9]+)\)", r"\1", json_data)
```

Note that `re.sub()` returns a copy of the string, just like the built-in [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method does.

Answer (score 0):

First point: [use `re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead of `str.replace()` here. Also note that python strings are immutable so in both case you have to rebind your string to the result of the function.

Second point: your file will OF COURSE not be updated if you don't explicitely do it by yourself - you have to write back the corrected string to the file (reopening the file in write mode).